# comparison / equality of two objects by protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to compare two Objective-C objects based purely on the protocol they implement.

Specifically I'm looking at comparing two objects conforming to [MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (iPhone mapkit annotations). Given two objects that conform to the protocol, I would like to determine if they are equal as far as the protocol is concerned. In this case, that would mean that at least the [coordinate](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MKAnnotation/coordinate) attribute is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a struct, you can compare the `coordinate` @properties of two `MKAnnotation`s with `==`. Example:

```
MKAnnotation *a1;
MKAnnotation *a2;

if(a1.coordinate == a2.coordinate) {
  //coordinates equal
}
```

**With the caveat**: you care comparing floating point values in the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` (the latitude and longitude fields of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` are of type `CLLocation` which is `typdef`ed as `double`). As always, comparing two floating point values for equality is fraught with subtlety. You may want to do a more involved comparison of the latitude and longitude values independently (e.g. checking wither their absolute difference is within some small range). See [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/oldverswitcher.html) for more info on this issue.

If you want to compare all properties, something like

```
(a1.coordinate == a2.coordinate) && [a1.title isEqualToString:a2.title] && [a1.subtitle isEqualToString:a2.subtitle]
```

(again with the save caveat) would do the trick.

Comment: You didn't really answer his question. Yours is specific to his example, but it looks like he wants a general solution.

Comment: Well, he did say "specifically I'm looking at comparing two objects conforming to MKAnnotation", so I think I did at least answer his specific question.

Comment: I kind of agree; I'm not sure how you can really "compare for equality based on protocol", unless you just mean you want to call -conformsToProtocol: on the instance first.

Comment: i got this error when i tried this method. invalid operand to binary == have 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'  and CLLocationCoordinate2D'.
i can get comparison when i trying if( (annotation.coordinate.latitude == existingannotations.coordinate.latitude) && (annotation.coordinate.longitude ==existingannotations.coordinate.longitude) )